# Can we ask about best translations or critical/scholarly editions here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I'm often at a loss as to which translation of a text I should read, if I haven't been specifically recommended an edition by a professor. For instance [these](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41650/for-kant-why-are-all-preferences-only-conditionally-valuable) two [questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51718/aristotle-on-unconditional-vs-universal-goods) of mine hinged on bad/misleading translations. I wasn't assigned those books for a class, so I wasn't looking for a particular edition, so I just read the first pdf available.

This goes double for foreign-language texts; I have no idea what publisher to go to if I want want to read Nietzsche or Kant in the original German.

I'm sure I'm not the only person having these problems; at a guess, most of the people on here are neither students nor professional philosophers, so their access to recommendations is even more limited than my own. Can we ask for such recommendations here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of (not closed!) questions regarding the best translation/edition, including on Kant, Hegel, Chinese philosophy or several dialogues of Plato. Just search for "translation" or "edition" on the main site.

The crucial thing to do is to specify your needs in a way so that there can be a more or less "correct" advice. Otherwise, I see no problem in asking for recommendations regarding translation.

Comment: ...I can't believe I didn't think to do a search before asking this question